# How to show TextView programmatically?

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` called `current_layout` which I place my views on. When I attempt to `addView(TextView)` , nothing is displayed. However when adding an `ImageView`, it works just fine. Why is my `TextView` not displaying?

```
public static void draw_shard(int x, int y, int amount_collected){//X and Y are GAMESURFACE values. Needs to increment by gamesurface y.

    ImageView shard = create_iv(); // Creates a new instance of an ImageView (parameter is the context of MainActivity)
    shard.setBackgroundDrawable(shard_icon);
    shard.setX(x);
    shard.setY(y+ImageLoader.get_score_bar_height());
    TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.current_context);
    tv.setX(shard.getX() + shard.getWidth());
    tv.setY(shard.getY());
    tv.setTypeface(Variables.joystix);
    tv.setTextSize(shard.getHeight());
    tv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText("+" + amount_collected);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    current_layout.addView(shard);
    current_layout.addView(tv);
}
```

I am adding the `TextView` on top of a black background also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with `shard.getWidth()` and `shard.getHeight()` , which were returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate and easy way to do that is:

Add the `TextView` in the layout file and set its visibility to gone, and when you need to show the `TextView`, just change the visibility of that `TextView`.

Sample code for `XML` file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout-width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <!-- Add other attributes too -->
```

And when you need that `TextView`, add this line of code:

```
findViewById("textview").setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById("textview").setText("" + amount_collected);
```

Answer (score 0):

But why are you adding `TextView` using java code?

You can easily do it in XML.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: this is silly. maybe his design doesn't require a textview to be drawn all the time? i create custom UIs in code because i have to..it displays information passed on what i got from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create LinearLayout
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

// Create TextView
TextView product = new TextView(this);
product.setText(" Product");
ll.addView(product);
```

Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

It will help you to understand

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
setContentView(linearLayout);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Your Text that you want to add");
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Thanks